# Split a block to multiple lines with respecting indenting

Tags: indentation, formatting

Context is Ruby. Lets say I have a long line which has a block which I want to have simply in multiple lines:

```
let:(variable) { do.some.stuff(expressed_as_a_long_line { x }) }
```

I'd like split this into multiple lines like this

```
let:(variable) {
  do.some.stuff(expressed_as_a_long_line { x }) 
}
```

...and later maybe even:

```
let:(variable) {
  do.some.stuff(
    expressed_as_a_long_line { x }
  ) 
}
```

Is there any simple inbuilt way or plugin for similar stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin `splitjoin.vim` is designed to do this and has support for ruby. https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim

For a vanilla solution:

```
function! OpenCode()
    call searchpair('{\|(', '', ')\|}', 'bW')
    exe 'normal!' "%i\<c-m>\<esc>%a\<c-m>\<esc>\<c-o>m]"
    normal! '[=']
    let l:save_slash = @/
    :'[,']s/\s\+$//e
    let @/ = l:save_slash
endfunction
nnoremap <c-b> :<c-u>call OpenCode()<cr>
```

Pressing Ctrl-B when *inside* a block will open it up.

Comment: splitjoin.vim is very cool, only that it forces multiline curly-braced blocks into do-end, which is something i would like to control. Maybe it can be configured?

And vanilla solution is also very cool, only that it leaves extra space at the end of the line. I don't know the syntax enough to understand how to control that either.

Thank you for your answer, I'm bit closer than before :)

Comment: I think it would be better to spell out all the characters that need to be entered literally. I don't think "etc." will be specific enough for many (most?) readers, particularly with regards to the escape character.

Comment: TaaviIlves, I don't use the plugin (or ruby) myself, but I think it is configurable and actively developed.  Added code to remove trailing whitespace.  A bit uglier but it should work.
@Rich you're right- I moved to a copy-paste-able solution.

Comment: That's not what I meant, but it's even better!

Comment: Thank you Rich! I leave it currently open for any other solution, but will mark it a solution, when noone replies.